2024 revision on radar plots - LuaLaTeX solution
Following up on this question, I want to create similar radar-like plots, and was looking for an appropriate 2024 update to do this (to integrate in a document I build with LuaLaTex).
The accepted answer using pst-plot seems easier and cleaner, but currently it produces the following plot, which is not nearly as nice as the plot shown for the accepted answer.
This is the code used:
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)%             user coordinates (is cm by default)
\psaxes[labels=none,axesstyle=polar,ticklinestyle=dashed,tickcolor=black!40](0,0)(-4,-4)(4,4)
\psaxes(0,0)(-4,-4)(4,4)%                  for the labels
\psset{fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.5}
\pswedge[fillcolor=green]{2.2}{120}{150}%  radius;startAngle;endAngle
\pswedge[fillcolor=yellow]{1.5}{150}{180}
\pswedge[fillcolor=red]{1.25}{180}{210}
\pswedge[fillcolor=red]{1.8}{210}{240}
\pswedge[fillcolor=green!100!white!80]{1.5}{240}{270}
\pswedge[fillcolor=orange]{2.4}{270}{300}
\pswedge[fillcolor=magenta]{2.2}{300}{330}
\pswedge[fillcolor=cyan]{0.6}{330}{360}
\psset{opacity=1}
\rput*[r](0,-3){\textbf{\textsf{Test B}}}
\rput*[r](4.5;135){\textbf{\textsf{Test A}}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}

Which produces:

The code is simple and elegant, but the plot is not exactly what I expected, as compared to the plot in the linked question, pasted below (circles in dashed lines do not show, transparency seems not working...):

I had tried the most voted non-accepted answer using the secdia package to good success in an older document, producing this:

However, I still find this secdia option a bit complicated and blackbox-y for me.
What I want is to reproduce this last plot (ignoring the grey background) with the pst-plot code above, or any other current alternative, that is elegant and easier to understand and modify.
Thanks!

The linked question and answer contains a lot of different code examples. Could you maybe pull the specific code you’re using into this question to make it self-contained, and explain more specifically you don’t like in the secdia version?

Just edited to make it more self-contained

I am getting close, but so far I do not seem to be able to remove the lines of the wedges, nor to make them transparent

Please check this new question for my progress with it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/730275/pst-plot-transparency-wedge-line-and-anchor

Couldn't see the circular grid too, even when running the original code with XeTeX ... However, you can always, and may be should, separate graphics from your main document. See e.g. this add legend question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/730821/245790 ) and elswhere. With this approach you can e.g. compile e.g. the graphic with XeTeX and still do your main document with LuaTeX.

This question already has a solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/730275/pst-plot-transparency-wedge-line-and-anchor

Here is an effort in Metapost -- the drawing language that is available in lualatex with the luamplib package.   You might find it "elegant and easy to understand".
The nice thing about MP is that you can do almost anything with the basic draw and fill commands, and you don't need to learn a complex sub-language to make charts.   This has a downside, because it means (for example) you have to do things like axes and scales "by hand" each time, but this tends to make you keep things simple.  And you can always write your own macros to avoid repetition if you are doing very many drawings.

Compile this code with lualatex to produce a PDF that looks like
the image above.
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans TC}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
vardef wedge(expr a, r) = origin -- subpath (0, a/45) of fullcircle scaled 2r -- cycle enddef;
vardef centroid expr p = origin for i=1 upto length p: + point i of p / length p endfor enddef;
input colorbrewer-rgb
beginfig(1);

  % data
  string name[]; numeric value[], theta[], N;
  name1 = "English";   value1 = 3.7;  theta1 = 90;
  name2 = "Español";   value2 = 3.9;  theta2 = 90;
  name3 = "中文";      value3 = 1.8;  theta3 = 90;
  name4 = "Italiano";  value4 = 3.1;  theta4 = 90;
  N = 4;

  % unit measure
  numeric u; u = 30; 

  % wedges and colours
  path w[]; color c[]; numeric a; a = 0;
  for i = 1 upto N:
    w[i] = wedge(theta[i], value[i] * u) rotated a; a := a + theta[i];
    c[i] = 1/2[white, Spectral[N][i]]; 
    fill w[i] withcolor c[i];
  endfor

  % draw the axes -- and scale
  path xx, yy;
  xx = (left -- right) scaled 4u;
  yy = xx rotated 90;
  drawoptions(withcolor 1/2);
  for i = 1 upto 4:
    draw (left--right) scaled 1/4u shifted (0,+i*u);
    draw (left--right) scaled 1/4u shifted (0,-i*u);
    draw (down--up)    scaled 1/4u shifted (+i*u,0);
    draw (down--up)    scaled 1/4u shifted (-i*u,0);
  endfor
  draw xx; draw yy;
  drawoptions();

  % label each wedge directly 
  for i = 1 upto N:
    label(name[i], centroid w[i]);
  endfor

  % alternatively, you could make a legend... 
  path mini; mini = wedge(42, 1/2u) rotated -21;
  picture legend; 
  legend = image(
    numeric x; x = 0;
    for i = 1 upto N:
      draw TEX(name[i]) shifted (x, 0);                   
      x := 3 + xpart lrcorner currentpicture;
      fill mini shifted (x, 3) withcolor c[i];
      x := 8 + xpart lrcorner currentpicture;
    endfor
  );
  label(legend, point 1/2 of bbox currentpicture shifted 21 down);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

Notes

the colours are from Color Brewer for MP

the font used is "Noto Sans TC" from Google which (a) looks nice in charts and (b) supports traditional Chinese -- (but it was missing one of the fancy characters in the OP's Chinese label, so I replaced the letters with what Google Translate gave me for "Chinese Language")

the wedge macro will work with any angles -- they don't have to be 90° -- but if the total goes over 360° your wedges will overlap

notice, in the code for the optional legend, that inside an image() macro, the built in <picture> currentpicture refers to the picture being created by the image() macro.

in the last line currentpicture refers to the whole image -- the line shows a convenient way to add a label centered at the bottom of a drawing.


You can find tutorials and reference material on the Metapost home page.
